# Java Threads not Running

Tags: java, multithreading

I had a thread that was working, but now that I added some code it doesn't run at all anymore. I tried without the code, and it works. Could someone please have a look at the code and make sure i haven't done anything wrong?

```
public class TimeBellServer extends Thread{
    static XBellDB[] xbellDB;
    static InterviewsDB[] interviewsDB;
    static boolean isPaused = false;
    static boolean bellsToday = false;

    public TimedBellServer() {

    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            xbellDB = new DBRefresh().refreshDB();
            System.out.println("Cody BAE");     
            //!this.isInterrupted() && 
            while(!TimedBellServer.isPaused) {
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                Date current = new Date();
                String formatCurrent = format.format(current);
                String date = formatCurrent + ":00";
                boolean anyRung = false;

                System.out.println("--TimedBellServer: The current system time is: " + date);

                if(bellsToday) {
                    for(int i = 0; i != xbellDB.length; i++) {
                        if(xbellDB[i].time.equals(date)) {
                            System.out.println("--TimedBellServer: Ringing bell \"" + xbellDB[i].name + "\"");
                            TCPConnection.isPaused = true;

                            GPIO.initiate(18);
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                            GPIO.bellOn();
                            Thread.sleep(8000);
                            GPIO.bellOff();
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                            GPIO.unExport();

                            TCPConnection.isPaused = false;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(ParentInterviews.parentInterviewsToday) {
                    if(interviewsDB[0].value.equals(date)) {
                        ParentInterviews.isPaused = false;
                        isPaused = true;
                        TCPConnection.isPaused = true;

                        System.out.println("--TimedBellServer: Parent Interviews First Block has started");
                    }

                    if(interviewsDB[1].value.equals(date)) {
                        ParentInterviews.isPaused = true;
                        TCPConnection.isPaused = false;

                        System.out.println("--TimedBellServer: Parent Interviews break has started");

                    }

                    if(interviewsDB[2].value.equals(date)) {
                        ParentInterviews.isPaused = false;
                        TCPConnection.isPaused = true;

                        System.out.println("--TimedBellServer: Parent Interviews Second Block has started");
                    }

                    if(interviewsDB[3].value.equals(date)) {
                        ParentInterviews.isPaused = true;
                        TCPConnection.isPaused = false;
                        isPaused = false;

                        System.out.println("--TimedBellServer: Parent Interviews Second Block has ended");
                    }
                }

                if(date.equals("00:01")) {
                    ParentInterviews.parentInterviewsToday = false;
                }

                if(anyRung == false) {System.out.println("--TimedBellServer: No bells rung");}
                Thread.sleep(60000);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    public static void refresh(XBellDB[] db) {
        xbellDB = db;
    }

    public static void refreshInterviews(InterviewsDB[] db) {
        interviewsDB = db;
    }
```

I use this to run the code:

```
Thread tbs = new Thread(new TimedBellServer());
tbs.start();
```

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't use `static` in this context (or at least be careful) as the moment you change the value, all the threads will get the same value

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: What part of the code causes the problem?

Comment: the snippet of code did not include what the actual class definition was.`TimedBellServer` should implement `Runnable` or extend `Thread` ?

Comment: please provide the relevant snap of code in which you are having issue.

Comment: WHen I run the piece of code below the large piece, it should run the code above as a thread, however none of it runs at all but my other threads run.

Comment: Also, the class TimedBellServer extends Thread

Comment: Also, catching exceptions and just ignoring them will cause questions of the sort of "why isn't my code working nothing seems to happen".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the question doesn't provide enough relevant info, I am going to hazard an educated guess here. The question doesn't provide any info about which piece of code was added that is causing the code to not run.

However, since you are not seeing any output at all (the result of the `println` statements), and since the second statement in the `run` method is a `println`, and I am sure that `t.start()` is pretty much guaranteed to call the `run` method,  I think that the line

```
xbellDB = new DBRefresh().refreshDB();
```

Is causing an exception. Since your `catch` block is catching all the `Exceptions` and swallowing them, without any kind of logging, I think you are not able to see any stacktrace or any other relevant info. Try adding something like

```
System.out.println(e.getMessage())
```

inside the main `catch` block of the `run` method and see if it helps.

Comment: I figured out that somehow another web server on port 80 was running alongside XAMPP without me knowing, and Google Chrome was showing XAMPP but Java was showing the other webserver. Thanks!